# Frost buildup on interior chimney stone and steps to address the problem?

Tags: fireplace, masonry, chimney, frost

Frost has built up on the gas fireplace chimney stone that intersects with the NE wall and the ceiling.

**Background info:**

This is the living room of our bungalow. The ceiling directly above that frost buildup is insulated (not insulated to the peak), so the attic is not temperature controlled.

The room is currently 10.5 degrees.

We have a boiler with cast iron rads but they have been turned off in this (sealed) room since the beginning of winter because I have been sanding and repainting the rads.

The fireplace has never been used by us (new homeowners).

**In your opinion:**

What would be involved to discover what is wrong? Cost?

Is this cause for alarm?

Could this in any way be related to a chimney cap that we were told should eventually be replaced?

Once the room is brought to temperature again, will the melting frost ruin insulation, drywall, etc?

If the room was to temperature, we likely wouldn’t have discovered this. Are we fortunate that this happened, rather than never not knowing about it?

[*And yes, I understand that keeping the room constantly heated is the solution. But that solution ignores the problem that this shouldn’t be occurring in the first place, regardless of the temperature of the room.*]

Comment: It will depend on the construction of the chimney, but cold air will come down, a cap will help a tiny bit.  Damage from the frost melting will depend on the amount, but should not be too much.  Would suggest using the fireplace a bit, but never used by you, would be a good idea to have it checked first.